# Entity Framework WPF/MVVM

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Am returning records in EF 4 in a WPF app using MVVM

Is there a way to give me a record ordinal for records returned.... ie 4 records would have 1 2 3 4 or 0 start...like in recordsets or datasets

Is there such a thing in EF?

Or if not has anyone got a way of doing this in my viewmodels as a property ie RowNo

cheers  George

Comment: Please just use the comment feature under individual answers if you wish to add a comment. If it won't fit in a comment, it probably belongs as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a Linq statement and do it in C#:

```
using (var database = new DataContext())
{
  int count = 0;
  this.YourDataBoundProperty = (
    from row in database.YourTable
    select new 
    {
      Id = count++,
      Column1 = row .Column1,
      Column2 = row .Column2,
      //.. etc.
    }
 ).ToArray();  //If you want an array
}
```

You can also use `let` to do this, but I prefer using a regular C# variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one way of doing this is by creating and working with [POCO classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx) (there is an [extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) for VS which makes it easy to do this)...

Obviously, your tables would contain an Id column of type int that is set to auto-increment...